# Google Apps script is running, but not sending any emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to setup a multi step email approval system. I have written a script, it is running but am not getting any email. Not able to get any reason.

```
function sendLeaveApprovalEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Loop through each row in the sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { // Start from row 2 (assuming row 1 is header)
    var row = data[i];

    // Check if the request is pending approval
    if (row[11] === "Pending") { // Assuming "Leave Status" is in column J
      var approver = row[8]; // Approver (Plant Manager or HR Manager)
      var approverEmail = approver === "Plant Manager" ? row[8] : row[9]; // Plant Manager Email Id or HR Email Id
      var employeeEmail = row[3]; // Employee Email Id
      var subject = "Leave Approval Request";
      var message = "Dear " + approver + ",\n\n";
      message += "Employee: " + row[1] + "\n";
      message += "Leave Type: " + row[5] + "\n";
      message += "Start Date: " + row[6] + "\n";
      message += "End Date: " + row[7] + "\n";
      message += "Please approve or reject this leave request by replying to this email.";

      // Send email to the current approver
      GmailApp.sendEmail(approverEmail, subject, message);

      // Update the "Leave Status" to indicate it's pending approval by the next level
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("Pending HR Approval"); // or "Approved" if this is the final level

      // Optionally, send a confirmation email to the employee
      var confirmationMessage = "Your leave request has been submitted for approval.";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(employeeEmail, "Leave Request Submitted", confirmationMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

i did try the above code but not able to get anything success.No one is getting email why though app script is running fine.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jydv3WFzVxAS2lZtijDLUvPb_n_Z3Hp8IJstjTY3xHU/edit?resourcekey#gid=743363784

Comment: with some `console.log` can you make sure the execution goes to `GmailApp.sendEmail(...)` ? Maybe you're never going to this line

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation:

### Script 1:

From your script, I have changed your ternary function condition from `var approverEmail = approver === "Plant Manager" ? row[8] : row[9];` to this `var approverEmail = row[8] != "" ? row[8]  : row[9];`

This will check if the plant manager cell is empty it will send an email to HR manager.

```
function sendLeaveApprovalEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

   // Loop through each row in the sheet
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { // Start from row 2 (assuming row 1 is header)
    var row = data[i];

    if (row[10] == "Pending") { // Assuming "Leave Status" is in column K
     
    // Approver (Plant Manager or HR Manager)
    
      var approverEmail = row[8] != "" ? row[8]  : row[9]; // Plant Manager Email Id or HR Email Id
      var employeeEmail = row[3]; // Employee Email Id
      var subject = "Leave Approval Request";
      var message = "Dear " + approverEmail + ",\n\n";
      message += "Employee: " + row[1] + "\n";
      message += "Leave Type: " + row[5] + "\n";
      message += "Start Date: " + row[6] + "\n";
      message += "End Date: " + row[7] + "\n";
      message += "Please approve or reject this leave request by replying to this email.";

      // Send email to the current approver
      GmailApp.sendEmail(approverEmail, subject, message);
      // Update the "Leave Status" to indicate it's pending approval by the next level
      

      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("Pending Approval");

      // send a confirmation email to the employee
      var confirmationMessage = "Your leave request has been submitted for approval.";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(employeeEmail, "Leave Request Submitted", confirmationMessage);
    }
  }
    }
```

### Script 2:

This function same as your script but this script used `filter()` and `map()`.

```
 function sendLeaveApprovalEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data1 = ss.getDataRange().getValues().filter(x => x[10] == "Pending" && x[8] != ""); //Filter all "Pending" entries for Plant Manager
  data1.map(x =>{
     GmailApp.sendEmail(x[8], "Leave Request Approval", constructEmailBody(x[8], x));
     GmailApp.sendEmail(x[3], "Leave Request Submitted", "Your leave request has been submitted for approval.");
  });
  var data2 = ss.getDataRange().getValues().filter(x => x[10] == "Pending" && x[8] == ""); //Filter all "Pending" entries for HR
  data2.map(x =>{
    GmailApp.sendEmail(x[9], "Leave Request Approval", constructEmailBody(x[9], x));
    GmailApp.sendEmail(x[3], "Leave Request Submitted", "Your leave request has been submitted for approval.");
  });
  var status = ss.getRange(1,11,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(x=>x=="Pending"?["Pending Approval"]:x);
  ss.getRange(1,11,status.length,status[0].length).setValues(status);
  
}


function constructEmailBody(approverEmail, data) {
  var message = "Dear " + approverEmail + ",\n\n";
  message += "Employee: " + data[1] + "\n";
  message += "Leave Type: " + data[5] + "\n";
  message += "Start Date: " + data[6] + "\n";
  message += "End Date: " + data[7] + "\n";
  message += "Please approve or reject this leave request by replying to this email.";
  return message;
}
```

### References:

- [SendMail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)
- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)